# Importing database from localhost to online host, but get an error

Tags: mysql

SQL query:

```
-- Constraints for dumped tables

-- Constraints for table `comment`

ALTER TABLE  `comment` 
ADD CONSTRAINT  `comment_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (  `user_id` ) 
REFERENCES  `user` (  `user_id` ),
ADD CONSTRAINT  `comment_ibfk_2` 
FOREIGN KEY (  `post_id` ) 
REFERENCES  `post` (  `post_id` );
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1005 - Can't create table akintltd_trial.#sql-aef76_8a1a0d (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)